# Reverse data constructor

Tags: haskell

How can I define a function that will accept my type and return its primitive "synonym"? For example:

```
newtype MyInt = MakeInt Int
```

And i want a function:

```
unMyInt :: MakeInt -> Int
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By pattern matching on the constructor:

```
unMyInt (MakeInt i) = i
```

Comment: @Ramesh: In any haskell tutorial or book (look for the chapter about pattern matching). It means "for any i, the result of applying `unMyInt` to the value `MakeInt i` is `i`".

Comment: @Ramesh: For example take a look at the [section about pattern matching](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#deftypes.pattern) from Real World Haskell.

Answer (score 15):

The other (and more comfortable way sometimes) is record syntax:

```
newtype myInt a = MyInt { unMyInt :: Int }
```

This automatically defines a function

```
unMyInt :: MyInt -> Int
```